# Azure Service Bus - SQLFilter doesn't works as expected

Tags: azureservicebus

Am trying to run the Azure Service Bus sample given in their official documentation at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/.

Creating subscriptions

```
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(TopicName, "CreatedMessages", new SqlFilter(@"Type = 'Created'"));
```

Sending Messages

```
public void SendMessages()
{
    var client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_connectionString, TopicName);

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var message = new BrokeredMessage("TestMessage " + i);

        if (i%2 == 0)
            message.Properties["Type"] = "Created";
        else
            message.Properties["Type"] = "All";

        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Handling Messages

```
    public void ListenMessages()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SubscribeMessages("CreatedMessages"));
    }

    public void SubscribeMessages(string subscription)
    {
        var allMessagesClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_connectionString, TopicName, subscription);

        allMessagesClient.OnMessage(message =>
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"** {subscription} **");
                Console.WriteLine("Body: " + message.GetBody<string>());
                Console.WriteLine("MessageID: " + message.MessageId);
                Console.WriteLine("Message Type: " + message.Properties["Type"]);
                Console.WriteLine();

                message.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                message.Abandon();
            }
        },
        new OnMessageOptions
        {
            AutoComplete = false,
            AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        });
    }
```

The above code works as expected.

However, problem am facing is that the moment the 'Type' property is renamed to anything else, like 'MessageType' or 'Name', the SQLFilter just stops working and i don't get any more messages.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that the old 'Type' based and new filter clash with each other? Remember that filters are persistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an expected behavior. The topic you create (`CreatedMessages`) is created once with the filter(s) and stored as-is. I.e. it's static. Whenever you decide that the filter needs to be changed, you should update your subscription to have a new filter.

To update an existing subscription with a new filter, you could look into [NamespaceManager.GetRulesAsync(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/dn130237.aspx) to get the existing rule(s) for your subscription and then remove the old one using [SubscriptionClient.RemoveRuleAsync(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.removeruleasync.aspx).